# 3D fitting with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following function

```
s(x,y,z) = e0 + t*(cos(x)*cos(y) + cos(y)*cos(z) + cos(z)*cos(x))
```

which maps three data points `x,y,z` onto a single energy (this is the dispersion of an fcc crystal in the tight-binding approximation). The problem is this: I have a datafile "test.dat" which is formatted like

```
x1 y1 z1 E1
...
```

a section of which is

```
0.000000 1.000000 0.500000 4.429
-0.016667 0.983333 0.500000 4.363
-0.033333 0.966667 0.500000 4.206
-0.050000 0.950000 0.500000 4.013
-0.066667 0.933333 0.500000 3.809
-0.083333 0.916667 0.500000 3.604
-0.100000 0.900000 0.500000 3.402
-0.116667 0.883333 0.500000 3.205
-0.133333 0.866667 0.500000 3.015
-0.150000 0.850000 0.500000 2.831
-0.166667 0.833333 0.500000 2.656
-0.183333 0.816667 0.500000 2.489
-0.200000 0.800000 0.500000 2.329
-0.216667 0.783333 0.500000 2.178
-0.233333 0.766667 0.500000 2.035
-0.250000 0.750000 0.500000 1.901
-0.266667 0.733333 0.500000 1.775
-0.283333 0.716667 0.500000 1.658
-0.300000 0.700000 0.500000 1.549
-0.316667 0.683333 0.500000 1.449
-0.333333 0.666667 0.500000 1.357
-0.350000 0.650000 0.500000 1.275
-0.366667 0.633333 0.500000 1.201
-0.383333 0.616667 0.500000 1.135
-0.400000 0.600000 0.500000 1.078
-0.416667 0.583333 0.500000 1.030
-0.433333 0.566667 0.500000 0.991
-0.450000 0.550000 0.500000 0.961
-0.466667 0.533333 0.500000 0.939
-0.483333 0.516667 0.500000 0.926
-0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.921
-0.483333 0.508333 0.508333 0.925
-0.466667 0.516667 0.516667 0.934
-0.450000 0.525000 0.525000 0.951
-0.433333 0.533333 0.533333 0.974
-0.416667 0.541667 0.541667 1.003
-0.400000 0.550000 0.550000 1.039
-0.383333 0.558333 0.558333 1.082
-0.366667 0.566667 0.566667 1.131
-0.350000 0.575000 0.575000 1.186
-0.333333 0.583333 0.583333 1.249
-0.316667 0.591667 0.591667 1.317
-0.300000 0.600000 0.600000 1.392
-0.283333 0.608333 0.608333 1.474
-0.266667 0.616667 0.616667 1.562
-0.250000 0.625000 0.625000 1.657
-0.233333 0.633333 0.633333 1.758
-0.216667 0.641667 0.641667 1.865
-0.200000 0.650000 0.650000 1.979
-0.183333 0.658333 0.658333 2.099
-0.166667 0.666667 0.666667 2.225
-0.150000 0.675000 0.675000 2.357
-0.133333 0.683333 0.683333 2.495
-0.116667 0.691667 0.691667 2.639
-0.100000 0.700000 0.700000 2.788
-0.083333 0.708333 0.708333 2.941
-0.066667 0.716667 0.716667 3.096
-0.050000 0.725000 0.725000 3.250
-0.033333 0.733333 0.733333 3.387
-0.016667 0.741667 0.741667 3.469
0.000000 0.750000 0.750000 3.450
```

The `x1,y1,z1,...` are inputs to `s(x,y,z)`; the `E1,...` are known energies. I would like to fit my function `s(x,y,z)` to the `E1,...`, using the row number in the datafile as the independent variable, and taking `e0,t` as parameters of the fit. I have tried

```
s(x,y,z) = e0 + t*(cos(x)*cos(y) + cos(y)*cos(z) + cos(z)*cos(x))
e0 = 14.5
t = -5.7

fit s(x,y,z) "test.dat" 0:(s($1,$2,$3)-$4) via e0,t

plot 'test.dat' u 0:(s($1,$2,$3)) w l , 'test.dat' u 0:4 w p
```

but this threw an error. Does anyone know if this is possible to do?

Comment: "...threw an error"...? Does this error maybe have some text? Btw, there is a `using` missing in the `fit` command. And can you maybe provide some minimal data for testing?

Comment: @theozh Of course, sorry: the error is "undefined variable z". It occurs even after I've added the missing ``using``

Comment: Could you please provide some minimal data for testing?

Comment: @theozh Of course - data has been added.

Comment: thanks for the data. Can you maybe add some datapoints where x and z are not = 0? Maybe about 100 datapoints (randomly or equally distributed) out of your full range of data?

Comment: @theozh Sure thing - I changed the selection of data. I should've mentioned that that nature of the data is such that only 1 or 2 columns usually vary at a time. The last 30 entries above are the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, it seems you have to explicitly define `z` as dummy variable.
Then you have `x,y,z` (or columns 1,2,3) as independent input variables and then you try to fit your function `s(x,y,z)` to column 4.

**Script:**

```
### fit with 3 independent variables
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.000000 1.000000 0.500000 4.429
-0.016667 0.983333 0.500000 4.363
-0.033333 0.966667 0.500000 4.206
-0.050000 0.950000 0.500000 4.013
-0.066667 0.933333 0.500000 3.809
-0.083333 0.916667 0.500000 3.604
-0.100000 0.900000 0.500000 3.402
-0.116667 0.883333 0.500000 3.205
-0.133333 0.866667 0.500000 3.015
-0.150000 0.850000 0.500000 2.831
-0.166667 0.833333 0.500000 2.656
-0.183333 0.816667 0.500000 2.489
-0.200000 0.800000 0.500000 2.329
-0.216667 0.783333 0.500000 2.178
-0.233333 0.766667 0.500000 2.035
-0.250000 0.750000 0.500000 1.901
-0.266667 0.733333 0.500000 1.775
-0.283333 0.716667 0.500000 1.658
-0.300000 0.700000 0.500000 1.549
-0.316667 0.683333 0.500000 1.449
-0.333333 0.666667 0.500000 1.357
-0.350000 0.650000 0.500000 1.275
-0.366667 0.633333 0.500000 1.201
-0.383333 0.616667 0.500000 1.135
-0.400000 0.600000 0.500000 1.078
-0.416667 0.583333 0.500000 1.030
-0.433333 0.566667 0.500000 0.991
-0.450000 0.550000 0.500000 0.961
-0.466667 0.533333 0.500000 0.939
-0.483333 0.516667 0.500000 0.926
-0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.921
-0.483333 0.508333 0.508333 0.925
-0.466667 0.516667 0.516667 0.934
-0.450000 0.525000 0.525000 0.951
-0.433333 0.533333 0.533333 0.974
-0.416667 0.541667 0.541667 1.003
-0.400000 0.550000 0.550000 1.039
-0.383333 0.558333 0.558333 1.082
-0.366667 0.566667 0.566667 1.131
-0.350000 0.575000 0.575000 1.186
-0.333333 0.583333 0.583333 1.249
-0.316667 0.591667 0.591667 1.317
-0.300000 0.600000 0.600000 1.392
-0.283333 0.608333 0.608333 1.474
-0.266667 0.616667 0.616667 1.562
-0.250000 0.625000 0.625000 1.657
-0.233333 0.633333 0.633333 1.758
-0.216667 0.641667 0.641667 1.865
-0.200000 0.650000 0.650000 1.979
-0.183333 0.658333 0.658333 2.099
-0.166667 0.666667 0.666667 2.225
-0.150000 0.675000 0.675000 2.357
-0.133333 0.683333 0.683333 2.495
-0.116667 0.691667 0.691667 2.639
-0.100000 0.700000 0.700000 2.788
-0.083333 0.708333 0.708333 2.941
-0.066667 0.716667 0.716667 3.096
-0.050000 0.725000 0.725000 3.250
-0.033333 0.733333 0.733333 3.387
-0.016667 0.741667 0.741667 3.469
0.000000 0.750000 0.750000 3.450
EOD

s(x,y,z) = e0 + t*(cos(x)*cos(y) + cos(y)*cos(z) + cos(z)*cos(x))
e0 = 14.5
t = -5.7
set dummy x,y,z
set fit brief nolog
fit s(x,y,z) $Data u 1:2:3:4 via e0,t
set palette rgb 33,13,10

splot $Data u 1:2:3:4 w p pt 7 lc palette 
### end of script
```

**Result:**

With your data subset you provided you will get the following fitted values for `e0` and `t`.

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
e0              = 21.3695          +/- 0.1207       (0.5649%)
t               = -8.84404         +/- 0.05524      (0.6246%)
```

The "3D"-plot represents column 4 as color from a palette.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I can't check this without example data but, I think you are specifying a independent variable = 0. From help:

For example, to generate the independent variable x as the sum of columns 2 and 3, while taking z from column 6 and requesting equal weights:

```
fit ... using ($2+$3):6
```

you are using

```
fit s(x,y,z) "test.dat" 0:(s($1,$2,$3)-$4)
```

Using the data row number as x would be ($0) or column(0). Also, I think you want to use column 4 as your z for the fit.

After a little more reading I think you need (from help fit):

```
using x1:x2:x3:z
```

which would be:

```
using 1:2:3:4
```

Another example from help fit:

```
set dummy x1, x2, x3, x4, x5
h(x1,x2,x3,x4,s5) = a*x1 + b*x2 + c*x3 + d*x4 + e*x5
fit h(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) 'foo.dat' using 1:2:3:4:5:6 via a,b,c,d,e
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately gnuplot still complains about "undefined variable z".